# Java disc-based HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm working on a web crawler (please don't suggest an existing one, it's not an option).
I have it working the way it is expected to. My only issue is that currently I'm using a sort of server/client model, where by the server does the crawling and processes the data, it then puts it in a central location.

This location is an object created from a class I wrote. Internally the class maintains a HashMap defined as `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`

I store data in the map with URL as a key (I keep these unique) and the HashMap value stores the corresponding data fields for that URL such as title or value.

I occasionally serialize the internal objects used, but the spider is multi threaded and as soon as I have say 5 threads crawling, the memory requirements go up exponentially.

So far the performance has been excellent with the HashMap, crawling 15K URLs in 2.r minutes with about 30 seconds CPU time so I really don't need to be pointed in the direction of an existing spider like most forum users have suggested.

Can anyone suggest a fast disc based solution that will probably support concurrent reading & writing? The data structure doesn't have to be the same, just needs to be able to store related meta tag values together etc.

Comment: because i tested it thoroughly and recorded memory usage and cpu time when only the amount of threads crawling are increased. There were the odd test that were outside and didn't really match the correlation shown by other tests but they were just treated as extreme values and ignored when i plotted, may not be some professional test but it was enough for my purpose.

Comment: Asking for software recommendations is off-topic here. See sister site: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: FYI, some relational database servers offer key-value stores. For example, Postgres has [*hstore*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html), and H2 has [*MVStore*](http://www.h2database.com/html/mvstore.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest using [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) for this, even though what you're building isn't really a cache. EhCache allows you to configure the cache instance so that it overflows to disc storage, while keeping the most recent items in memory. It can also be configured to be disc-persistent, i.e. data is flushed to disc on shutdown, and read back into memory at startup. On top of all that, it's key-value based, so it already fits your model. It supports concurrent access, and since the disk storage is managed as a separate thread, you shouldn't need to worry about disk access concurrency.

Alternatively, you could consider a proper embedded database such as [Hypersonic](http://hsqldb.org/) (or numerous others of a similar style), but that's probably going to be more work.

Comment: I went for an embedded db instead, using hsqldb 
thanks for the suggestion everyone, it was much appreciated

Comment: For future reference to anyone looking for something like this. I Implemented hsqldb and hypersonic but both cause seriously high CPU usage. Testing an implementation of sqlite, from http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ so far having better results

Answer (score 2):

[JDBM2](http://code.google.com/p/jdbm2/) library provides persistent maps for Java. Its fast and thread-safe.

**UPDATE**:
Evolved into [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org) project

Answer (score 1):

There is [Tokyo Cabinet](http://1978th.net/tokyocabinet/), which is a fast implementation of a disk-based hash table.

In your case, I think the best way to store values in such a setup would be to prefix the metadata keys with the url:

```
[url]_[name] => [value]
[url]_[name2] => [value2]
```

Unfortunately, I'm not sure you can enumerate the metadata for a given URL, using this solution.

If you want to use a more structured data store, there are also MongoDB, and SQLite, which I would recommend.

Comment: as with the above i'm looking into tokyo cabinet thanks for the suggestion, i'll get bk to everyone after i see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

what about using JPA in your class, and persist data in a database (that can be text based like sqlite)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API

Comment: I'm already serializing but the objects are loaded back on to the heap anyway with their original size which defeats the whole point

Comment: no JPA is not about serialising, it is about persisting objects to database. Your object is persisted to the database and not loaded back (well java objects are not destroyed, they are garbage collected when they are dereferenced)

Answer (score 0):

[Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) is an embeddable, hash-based Java data store, persisting the data to disk (to a single file), which targets to be a drop-in replacement of `ConcurrentHashMap` (provides the same `ConcurrentMap` interface). Chronicle Map is [the fastest store among similar solutions](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#features) and features excellent read/write concurrency, scaling almost linearly to the number of available cores in the machine.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Chronicle Map.