# low cpu footprint java embeded database

Tags: java, embedded-database

This is a follow up to  a question i asked at [java disc based hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316630/java-disc-based-hashmap) for a disk based hashmap.

The solution suggested works but at a high CPU cost. I've tried using a few embeded databases, including hsqldb and derby as well as an sqllite implementation in java.

The all get the job done, quite slowly for most of the ones i've tried, the three i mentioned beformed the best. I ran into one problem with all of them however.
Starting and maintaining each embeded database required a lot of CPU time, the ones i haven't mentioned used up 100% of the cpu most of the time,according to task manager.

My new question then is, are there any simple disc based storage that won't eat away my cpu.

for the record, the sqllite solution didn't spike cpu usage it was just crashing with a range of different errors. And apache derby had the best performance and cpu usage fluctuated with it but on average was about 80%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with other embedded java DB then Apache Derby and HSQLDB.
Some links:

- [Open Source Database Engines in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/database-engines)
- [LinkedIn answers](http://www.linkedin.com/answers/technology/software-development/TCH_SFT/1207-3692603)

Did you tried some NoSQL DB?

#### Update

Here is a [list of NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases. I have no experience with them. But MongoDB and CouchDB are quite famous. And also [Db4o looks interesting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o#Embeddable).

Comment: looking into this "bigtable" by google. Looks interesting http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction.html

Comment: There any NoSQL db you would suggest? I had a look around and found the bigtable, do you have any experience with any in paticular?

Answer (score 0):

Try [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)