# How to save part of a TreeSet to file efficiently? and reload it? (Java question)

Tags: java, file-io, file, treeset

I'm working with a TreeSet to store some information, so that it is sorted according to some order.

When the TreeSet becomes very large (>1GB), I want to save the smallest elements in the TreeSet to a file, to free some RAM.  Then later, when there is more free RAM, I want to be able to reload these elements into memory to process them.

My question is:  is there some **efficient** way of storing part of a TreeSet to file and restoring them into memory later?

Note that when I reload the elements into memory, it could be part of a new TreeSet or into the same TreeSet.

Thanks for any idea about how to do this!

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316630/java-disc-based-hashmap) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you using the TreeSet for? Do the contents change often? Are you trying to be efficient in terms of speed, or disk usage?

Reading and writing to a File is very slow compared to memory, and keeping the file and memory versions in sync might be challenging if they change often.

Maybe it makes sense to use a database. There are several lightweight databases such as derby and sqllite which can be embedded in your application. Databases are designed to worry about the memory vs. file issue, and if you have >1Gb of data, maybe it makes sense to organise it.

Comment: I mean efficient in term of execution time (speed).   In my application I need to maintain a collections of elements sorted, and I need to perform constantly the following operations: (1) insert an element (2) remove an element, (3) find the maximum element according to the order.  I used a TreeSet because it is based on a red-black tree and it provides O(log(n)) worst case time for these operations. My application consume a lot of memory. So i'm looking for a way to save part of the TreeSet to disk and reload it later to reduce the memory usage.

Comment: My idea is that when the memory reach 1GB for example, I will save half of the tree to a file, and then process the other half that is in memory. When I finish processing the part that is in memory, I will reload the other half into memory to process it, if necessary.

Comment: My application has to always process the maximum element in the TreeSet first because it is the most "promising". When the element is processed, it is removed from the TreeSet. And constantly some new elements are added to the TreeSet.