# Best practice of creating a 100K elements in a Set collection in Java

Tags: multithreading, elasticsearch, collections, java-8, set

Creating an Injector application for Elasticsearch to do performance testing on a project I'm working on. I have users and each user has activities per day, an activity can be making/receiving a phone call, doing a meeting, sending/receiving email, etc. I run the Injector as a Java application with arguments *number-of-users*, *number-of-activities-per-day-per-user* and *number-of-days*. The user names (first and last name) must be unique. To do so I have a list of 5000 first-names and a list of 5000 last-names, to make the user names unique I randomly select first-name and last-name from the lists, the unique users names I store in a `Set` and when I have the complete list I send it to the Injector that randomly creates activities for each user using **Stream API** `.parallelStream()`.

My first performance test in for 500 users with 30 events per day per user and for 5 workdays = 75K documents. Creating the data for this test goes smooth, I create 500 unique user names into a `Set` collection and `Thread`s go over the collection creating the activities for each user.

My challenge is in the second test (and I guess will continue to the next test) where I need data of 50K users: when the collection with user names is created I get `OutOfMemoryException` after about 10K users.

Is there a way to create the collection of user names that will keep the names unique and not cause an `OutOfMemoryException`?

I will appreciate any assistance, tip, and comment.

Comment: Possible you want to store your 50K unique Users on disk: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316630/java-disc-based-hashmap   Or store only the hashValue of your names in memory and work on the last 1K real user-names (do not generate a user with the same hashValue a second time).

Comment: I don't really care where to store the list, as long as I keep unique names. I tried keeping it on the disk (HDD) but lost the uniqueness and the performance of creating the list got unacceptable. The link looks promising mainly the MapDB. Thank you.